# how to fix: silverlight draggable window-The property 'System.Windows.Controls.Border.Child' is set more than once.

Tags: silverlight, xaml, arcgis

Would appreciate any idea how to approach this: I get this  exception at Initialize Component(): I think the problem is in my grid in the  XAML code, any ideas?

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  Message=The property 'System.Windows.Controls.Border.Child' is set more than once. 
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
       at Minimal.MainPage.InitializeComponent()
       at Minimal.MainPage..ctor()
  InnerException:

```
            <basics:GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

            <Grid Margin="5" Grid.Column="2" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Name="SearchTextBox" Text="JOHN" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,2,5,2" />
                    <Button Content="Search by owner name" Click="Button_Click" 
                    Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                </StackPanel>
                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
                    <esri:FeatureDataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid"
            Map="{Binding ElementName=MyMap}" 
            GraphicsLayer="{Binding ElementName=MyMap, Path=Layers.[MontgomeryParcels]}" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>

        </Border>

    </userControls:DraggableWindow>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all we can see is the ending tag for one border, and I see you have multiple things stuffed in that Border (your `GridSplitter` and your `Grid`) I would say without seeing the whole snippet you need to give all your objects in that border one parent container and you'll be good to go since Border will only accept one child.

So for example, instead of;

```
<Border>
    <Object/>
    <Object/>
    <Object/>
</Border>
```

You need something more like;

```
<Border>
    <ContentContainer><!-- Grid, or StackPanel, or whatever you choose -->
        <Object/>
        <Object/>
        <OBject/>
    </ContentContainer>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem-removed code from grid inside draggable window to main project grid. It is now a menu item.